# chrome loads old html file

Tags: angular, google-chrome, browser-cache, cache-control

I have an angular application and when I open a route, after a release had been made, I will get a broken page.
This is because, the main html page would be retreived from the cache and the JS bundle it is expecting will not be present.  The server would deliver a not-found html causing the application to endlessly wait.

I checked the headers we are returning for the html and I am expecting it to expire in 5 mins.

etag: "5f2d6f5b-1b5f"
expires: Sun, 09 Aug 2020 16:18:40 GMT
cache-control: max-age=300

when I simply refresh the page, everything will start working.  Also, I am never able to replicate this issue if I have the developer tools open.  Is there any way to check what the browser has in its cache and why it would not expire it?  I am on ubuntu.

I dont see this trouble in firefox (proably I use it less frequently).  I am expecting my users to also get affected by this.  hence trying to understand this in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was nothing to do with Chrome !!  It was with nginx.

Nginx was not setting the same expiry to 200 vs 304 response.  When we force chrome a refresh, it sends a regular get and gets a 200 ok response.  But when it initiates the get with if-modified-since or If-None-Match then the 304 response comes back with a large cache expiry set as default, as there is no content type in these responses.

For the guys who have come to this question, I am leaving the solution for nginx here.

https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/issues/230

Issue reported to nginx and work around suggested there.  Here is the final content type based caching recommended.

https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/533d401ea211e074a92048dc53da63f4e8d8ad9d/h5bp/web_performance/cache_expiration.conf

note the way an entry with empty content type is mapped to off.

# No content

""                                      off;

This is the path traversed by 304 response and does not cause any trouble now.